# How do I get a unique 8 character string from a 24 character string?

Tags: php, string, mongodb, unique

I would like to get a 8 character string from a unique 24 character string so as to make a shortened URL. The 8 character string HAS to be based on the unique 24 character string. If I make a random 8 character string then there will have to be a database lookup to see it's not already taken. Also I don't want to use the first 8 characters or last 8 characters of the 24 character string. The 24 characters are a MongoDB Object Id. Thanks.

Comment: If you really want to be sure that you don't have any collision, you won't get around doing a lookup, as there are more 24 character strings than there are 8 character strings. So whatever mapping from 24 characters to 8 you choose, it can be unique from 24 to 8 but not the other way around. To minimize the chance of a collision though, you should look at hash functions.

Comment: @ahans: how applying hash function may *minimize* the chance of a collision?

Comment: @zerkms Good hash functions take care of evenly distributing  values in the space of possible hash values. Maybe _minimize_ wasn't a good word, _reduce_ is probably better.

Comment: @ahans: you already have the unique hash-alike string. Any reason to perform another hashing function over it?

Comment: @zerkms Well, if the string already is like a hash, there's no point in hashing it again, you can as well just truncate it.

Comment: @ahans: that's was my point actually when I replied you :-) (PS: I'm not an OP)

Comment: @ahans: but that's at the cost of greatly increasing the chance of a collisions. a full 40 character sha1 has is for all intents and purposes unique. but any arbitrary 8 character sequence of that same hash is most definitely going to be much easier to collide. OP wants to be guaranteed no collisions without having to do any looks, which is not possible

Comment: @MarcB I totally agree with that, that's why I said in the first comment that it won't be possible to reduce this to 8 characters and at the same time avoid collisions. I didn't know that the MongoDB Object Id already is a hash.

Comment: @ahans: it's not technically a "hash", but a serialized bunch of data. In this case it doesn't matter though.

Answer (score 3):

8 is too few.

Here is how you can get 16 from 24:

```
$id = '507f191e810c19729de860ea';

$str = base64_encode(implode('', array_map(function($c) { return chr(hexdec($c)); }, str_split($id, 2))));

var_dump($str); // UH8ZHoEMGXKd6GDq
```

For less characters you need to have bigger character base, but the thing is - there are no url safe left.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your 24 char string is upper+lower alpha-numeric, that'd be

```
26+26+10 chars = 62 chars = 6 bits required to present them, and
24 * 6 = 144 bits to store them.
```

144bits/8bits/byte = 18 bytes. you cannot compress your 24 chars into 8 characters without having a potential collision. 8 chars at 8bits/char = 64bits maximum.

Comment: A side note: this is true for small volumes, which are compression-inefficient

Comment: It's even worse since the OP wants to reduce it to 8 characters which assumingly also can only be upper+lower alpha-numeric.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there's a way to do this unless you are sure that the string with 24 characters have some pattern and from that pattern you maybe could make a 8 character unique string. You could use md5 to create 32 characters unique string and for example take the middle 8 characters but it only reduces the chance of collision and there's no guarantee that it is unique

Comment: **why** to hash and take 8 chars of a hash when you can just take 8 chars of mongodb object id?

Comment: I said just to reduce the collision. There's no way to generate 8 character uique string. The possibility of collision in 8 characters from 32 character string is less than 8 characters from 24 characters string

Comment: my question was: why to hash a hash? The mongodb object id is **already a hash**. Why do you propose to hash it once again?

Comment: I say again: hash with md5 TO CREATE UNIQUE 32 characters. And the possibility of collision in 8 characters from 32 character string is less than 8 characters from 24 characters string. It is just for reducing the collision

Comment: "TO CREATE UNIQUE" - that's wrong. md5 doesn't guarantee uniqueness. You already have hex-based string, the collision probability for them is the same. Just hold you breath and try to accept that lol )) "And the possibility of collision in 8 characters from 32 character string is less than 8 characters from 24 characters string." --- who told you so? )) the probability is the same - 1/8^16 (assuming both are evenly distributed)